# I have 9 monitors, 2 GPU's, and Windows 10 doesn’t read 5 of them, but Ubuntu 20.04 does. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, gpu

I use 9 monitors day-to-day for stock trading and 3D design, rigging characters.

I have 2 RX580s and they work 100% fine on Linux, but when I switch over to my Windows installation on a different drive, only one of the GPUs is used, I can see the other GPU in the device manager, but the monitors don't work at all. This is very strange because all the monitors worked when I connected them the first time, on Windows, and on Linux.

Over time (2 weeks) the monitors just one day went black, and now do not work on Windows. It is odd because I know the panels work!

They boot up with Linux and I am able to use them all normally. It’s just with Windows that I am experiencing issues.

Would anyone be able to help please?

Comment: In Windows you have the AMD software to manage everything graphics related. Please check and if you have newer info to add then please [edit] the question to update it.